# Add logo to Flutter layout

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am completely new to Flutter UI design and I am trying to add a logo to a login screen. I went thru a tutorial for the login screen and have it working but I cannot get a logo centered above the form itself. Ive serached other tutorials and gone thru layout walkthru's but cant get it correct. The tutorial had a background image which i was able to figure out but we just want the logo. Here is the dart code.

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:lbconnect/auth.dart';
import 'package:lbconnect/data/database_helper.dart';
import 'package:lbconnect/models/user.dart';
import 'package:lbconnect/screens/login_screen_presenter.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
@override
State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
// TODO: implement createState
return new LoginScreenState();
}
}

class LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen>
implements LoginScreenContract, AuthStateListener {
BuildContext _ctx;

bool _isLoading = false;
final formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();
final scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
String _password;
String _username;

LoginScreenPresenter _presenter;

LoginScreenState() {
_presenter = new LoginScreenPresenter(this);
var authStateProvider = new AuthStateProvider();
authStateProvider.subscribe(this);
}

void _submit() {
final form = formKey.currentState;

  if (form.validate()) {
  setState(() => _isLoading = true);
  form.save();
  _presenter.doLogin(_username, _password);
  }
  }

  void _showSnackBar(String text) {
   scaffoldKey.currentState
    .showSnackBar(new SnackBar(content: new Text(text)));
 }

  @override
  onAuthStateChanged(AuthState state) {

  if(state == AuthState.LOGGED_IN)
  Navigator.of(_ctx).pushReplacementNamed("/home");
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 _ctx = context;
 var loginBtn = new RaisedButton(
  onPressed: _submit,
  child: new Text("LOGIN"),
  color: Colors.white,
  );
  var loginForm = new Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    new Form(
      key: formKey,
      child: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: new TextFormField(
              onSaved: (val) => _username = val,
              validator: (val) {
                return val.length < 10
                    ? "Username must have atleast 10 chars"
                    : null;
              },
              decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: "EMAIL"),
            ),
          ),
          new Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: new TextFormField(
              onSaved: (val) => _password = val,
              decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: "PASSWORD"),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    _isLoading ? new CircularProgressIndicator() : loginBtn
  ],
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
);



return new Scaffold(
  appBar: null,
  key: scaffoldKey,
  body: new Container(
    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.blue,
    ),

    child: new Center(
      child: new ClipRect(
        child: new BackdropFilter(
          filter: new ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 10.0, sigmaY: 10.0),
          child: new Container(
            child: loginForm,
            height: 300.0,
            width: 300.0,
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.transparent,
            )
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

```
 @override
 void onLoginError(String errorTxt) {
 _showSnackBar(errorTxt);
setState(() => _isLoading = false);
  }

@override
void onLoginSuccess(User user) async {
_showSnackBar(user.toString());
setState(() => _isLoading = false);
var db = new DatabaseHelper();
await db.saveUser(user);
var authStateProvider = new AuthStateProvider();
authStateProvider.notify(AuthState.LOGGED_IN);
}
}
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjI6z.png)

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your code and make sure that logo you want to insert should be in the assets if you are using a asset image. For more information go for [this](https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/).
I hope it helps you with what you want:)

```
Widget ui(){
 return Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    SizedBox(height: 50.0),
    DecoratedBox(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
      image: AssetImage('graphics/logo.png')
    )
    new Form(
      key: formKey,
      child: new Column(
    .........
     ...........
);
}
```

Comment: Absoultely. I'll add a picture. There is no code for it because what I added broke the app :(    Basically we need our logo centered in the top of the app above the login form.

Comment: I added a screenshot with a logo where we need it.

Comment: thanks for the help, do I add this before the new form ?

Comment: Im not seeing where exactly to add this, I have a var declared for the button and the form in my version.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are couple of ways to do that one is by using a **Column widget** where any widgets you wrap into the column get aligned vertically. By default, everything inside a column is padded to center.

```
Column(
       children: <Widget>[
             LogoWidget(),
             EmailWidget(),
             PasswordWidget(),
             ButtonWidget(),
          ],
      ),
```

but this will start from Top of the page you can either provide some margin by wrapping it inside a container but giving it some hardcoded values isn't a good idea,
the best Way I know is to use **Flex with Expanded Widget** where you specify How much of the screen space is used by a particular Widget and that works perfectly fine on all screen sizes.

```
Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Container(), // empty container to leave some space at the top
            flex: 2,
          )
          Expanded(
            child: LogoWidget(),
            flex: 3,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: EmailWidget(),
            flex: 2,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: PasswordWidget(),
            flex: 2,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ButtonWidget(),
            flex: 2,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(), // empty container to leave some space at bottom
            flex: 2,
          )
        ],
      ),
```

Just play with the flex values this will give you your result, that's a fun way to build layouts with flutter

I would recommend you to read this post to learn more about flutter layouts 
https://medium.com/coding-with-flutter/flutter-layouts-walkthrough-row-column-stack-expanded-padding-5ed64e8f9584